# How to get total count of Active Directory users by using of Azure Mgmt SDK fluent

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-management-api

I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent for getting resources in Azure with programmatically(C# .NET-Core Web app) and tried to get resources information by providing service principals as below....

```
string subscriptionId="XXX"; 
   AzureCredentials cred = new 
             AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(UIConstants.ClientID, 
             UIConstants.Secret, UIConstants.Tenant,AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);                      
            
    var azure = Azure.Configure()
                     .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic) 
                     .Authenticate(cred) 
                     .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

When I tried to get total numbers of count of Active Directory users like this:

```
int identity = azure.AccessManagement.ActiveDirectoryUsers.List().ToArray().Length;
```

I got this exception in code:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Please help me to fix above issue..

Thanks,
Tutul

Comment: Apologize for incomplete question.Exception is coming as "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'".

Comment: It means you don’t have sufficient access privileges to enumerate all AAD objects (Also, please note that AAD is not AD)

Comment: Thanks for replay @Dai. But , i can access others azure resources info  like vm, storages. Can u pls elaborate and give some more details..?
Thanks,

Comment: Just because your access-token/user has permission to access VMs and storage doesn’t mean you have permission to access all users. Check what permissions you’re requesting when you authenticate, and check your user permissions in the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure resources like VM, storages are stored under the subscription. But AAD users are stored under directory.

You need to assign the service principal a `Directory readers` role.

Go to **Azure Portal** -> **Azure Active Directory** -> **Roles and administrators** -> **Directory readers** -> **+Add assignments**, enter the client id of the service principal.

Now the service principal should have access to the Azure AD users.

Comment: Many Thanks @Allen Wu. 
My role as 'Application administrator' at ADD of azure subscription and  i checked that 'add assignment' button  is disabled at Directory readers..  i am not able to do that.   What role i require ? Pls help

Comment: @AnirbanGoswami You should ask an global admin to do this for you.

Comment: Got it.. It is working now.. Many Thanks!!
I also tried to get alert as below but it gace an exception..
int alert = azure.AlertRules.MetricAlerts.List().ToArray().Length +
                         azure.AlertRules.ActivityLogAlerts.List().ToArray().Length;

Any suggestion or help ,pls

Comment: Many Thanks!! it helps a lots